# Submit form and file to controller codeigniter

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, curl

I am newbie in codeigniter and MVC model
i want to know how i passing my form and file upload to controller and upload it using curl
and return the confirmation result to view

this is my view :
    
            Edit Issue

```
            <form class="editissueform">
            <h7>Name : </h7>
            <input type="text" name="issue_name"><br>
            <h7>Tagline:</h7>
            <input type="text" name="issue_tagline"><br>
            <h7>Description:</h7>
            <input type="text" name="issue_description"><br>
            <h7>Publish Date:</h7>
            <input type="text" name="issue_publish_on"><br>
            </form>                 
        </div>
        <h4>Upload Publication</h4>
        <div class="issuedit">
            <form class="editissueform">
            <input type="file" name="issue_file" size="40" />
            <h7>Please Upload using pdf file format</h7>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

and this is my controller:

```
$issue_name = $this->input->post('issue_name');
  $issue_tagline = $this->input->post('issue_tagline');
  $issue_description = $this->input->post('issue_description');
  $issue_publish_on = $this->input->post('issue_publish_on');
  $issue_file = $this->input->post('issue_file');

$data2=array(
  'issue_name' => $issue_name,
  'issue_tagline' => $issue_tagline,
  'issue_description' => $issue_description,
  'issue_file' => $issue_file
  ); 

$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->view('issue_detail',$data2);


  echo $issue_name;

  $target_url = 'https://platform.twixlmedia.com/admin-api/1/upload';

  $file_name_with_full_path = realpath($issue_file);
  $post3 = array(
'admin_api_key'    => 'da06751194bc1xxxxxxxxxxxx',
'app_key'          => 'bd7cf04226c587xxxxxxxxxxx',
'issue_identifier' => $productid,
'issue_file'       =>'@' . realpath($issue_file),
'issue_name'       => $issue_name
  );

$ch3 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://platform.twixlmedia.com/admin-api/1/upload');
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post3);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result3 = curl_exec($ch3);
curl_close ($ch3);
echo $result3;
```

how i can passing my form input to controller and upload them to server api?
thanks

Comment: form action is missing

Comment: `<h7>`? HTML doesn't have an `<h7>`. It only goes up to sub-sub-sub-sub-sub-headings (which is more than most people need). Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: thanks for replying. i will use label now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML `<form>` tag is missing attributes:

```
<form class="editissueform" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

- action
- method
- enctype

---

### Debugging update

**Your HTML form**

```
<form class="editissueform" action="www.example.com/process/curl" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- all of your form stuff -->
</form>
```

**process.php controller**

```
<?php

class Process extends CI_controller
{
    public function curl()
    {
        /**
         *
         * Does this output what you expect?
         *
         */

        echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->input->post(), true).'</pre>'

        die();

        // All of your curl code
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks i add the attributes but still not working. Is there another besides attirbutes that i'm missing here iam very newbie at this sorry for bad question like this

Comment: the input data from form in the view. I am testing the data is passing to controller or not by echo $issue_name in controller but it's not working.

Comment: @SamuelBilly I don't know what your issue is unless you post your updated `<form>` code along with the relevant CodeIgniter code. Please see my update for debugging help.

Comment: i got it work. mistype in attributes thanks for your help